# Is there a way to sort the console and network, by time for XHTTP requests in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For example in the network panel, we can sort by method, status, type etc etc, in ascending or descending order.

Is there a way to sort it such that the latest requests appear at the top for network and console panel, so we don't have to keep scrolling down to see the latest requests.

I saw it happened before in Chrome canary (network panel) some time back, but it has since defaulted back to appending new requests at the bottom.

Using Version 33.0.1709.2 canary

Comment: terrible UI... it's 2017 and the answer still isn't obvious

Answer (score 25):

Here we go, I found it. It would be difficult to hide it better!

Some further googling produced answers for older versions of Chrome, but the instructions screenshots were outdated and didn't make sense anymore.

Here's how to restore chronological sort order for the `Network` tab:

1. Right click the `Waterfall` column header
2. In the popup menu, mouse-over `Waterfall` to reveal the submenu
3. Click `Start Time`

Step 3 selects the sort *criterion* ... once it's set to `Start Time`, you can just click the `Waterfall` column header to toggle ascending/descending order.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's changed in the meantime. On Google Chrome version `87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)` one can simply click on `Waterfall` and it will sort. Click again and it will sort the other way around. I agree, it's really not clear in the UI on first sight:

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you debug something and can see only the *Name* column and if you accidentally click the header it becomes sorted alphabetically by name:
[image]

To quickly fix this just context-menu-click on the *Name* column and select **Sort By** > **Waterfall**:

[image]